# How can I parse this JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

How can I parse this JSON in Swift?
This JSON is from an API, and the API provider explained the JSON's "data" object like this.
[Screenshot of the description.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaGT6.png)
The problem is that the JSON Decoder can't decode the JSON at all. Its error message is "type mismatch".

```
{
    "meta": {
        "last_updated_at": "2023-02-15T12:59:59Z"
    },
    "data": {
        "ADA": {
            "code": "ADA",
            "value": 0.001978
        },
        "AED": {
            "code": "AED",
            "value": 0.002859
        },
        "AFN": {
            "code": "AFN",
            "value": 0.0696
        },
        "ALL": {
            "code": "ALL",
            "value": 0.084096
        },
        "AMD": {
            "code": "AMD",
            "value": 0.306311
        },
        "ANG": {
            "code": "ANG",
            "value": 0.001403
        },
        "AOA": {
            "code": "AOA",
            "value": 0.392615
        },
        "ARS": {
            "code": "ARS",
            "value": 0.149368
        },
        "AUD": {
            "code": "AUD",
            "value": 0.00113
        },
        "AVAX": {
            "code": "AVAX",
            "value": 4.2e-5
        },
        "AWG": {
            "code": "AWG",
            "value": 0.001403
        },
        "AZN": {
            "code": "AZN",
            "value": 0.001323
        },
        "BAM": {
            "code": "BAM",
            "value": 0.001421
        },
        "BBD": {
            "code": "BBD",
            "value": 0.001572
        },
        "BDT": {
            "code": "BDT",
            "value": 0.082699
        },
        "BGN": {
            "code": "BGN",
            "value": 0.00142
        },
        "BHD": {
            "code": "BHD",
            "value": 0.000293
        },
        "BIF": {
            "code": "BIF",
            "value": 1.616223
        },
        "BMD": {
            "code": "BMD",
            "value": 0.000778
        },
        "BNB": {
            "code": "BNB",
            "value": 3.0e-6
        },
        "BND": {
            "code": "BND",
            "value": 0.001039
        },
        "BOB": {
            "code": "BOB",
            "value": 0.005378
        },
        "BRL": {
            "code": "BRL",
            "value": 0.004062
        },
        "BSD": {
            "code": "BSD",
            "value": 0.000778
        },
        "BTC": {
            "code": "BTC",
            "value": 0
        },
        "BTN": {
            "code": "BTN",
            "value": 0.064445
        },
        "BWP": {
            "code": "BWP",
            "value": 0.010201
        },
        "BYN": {
            "code": "BYN",
            "value": 0.001965
        },
        "BYR": {
            "code": "BYR",
            "value": 15.257164
        },
        "BZD": {
            "code": "BZD",
            "value": 0.001569
        },
        "CAD": {
            "code": "CAD",
            "value": 0.001044
        },
        "CDF": {
            "code": "CDF",
            "value": 1.591884
        },
        "CHF": {
            "code": "CHF",
            "value": 0.000718
        },
        "CLF": {
            "code": "CLF",
            "value": 2.2e-5
        },
        "CLP": {
            "code": "CLP",
            "value": 0.614919
        },
        "CNY": {
            "code": "CNY",
            "value": 0.005326
        },
        "COP": {
            "code": "COP",
            "value": 3.698284
        },
        "CRC": {
            "code": "CRC",
            "value": 0.442391
        },
        "CUC": {
            "code": "CUC",
            "value": 0.000782
        },
        "CUP": {
            "code": "CUP",
            "value": 0.01868
        },
        "CVE": {
            "code": "CVE",
            "value": 0.080125
        },
        "CZK": {
            "code": "CZK",
            "value": 0.017217
        },
        "DJF": {
            "code": "DJF",
            "value": 0.138581
        },
        "DKK": {
            "code": "DKK",
            "value": 0.005422
        },
        "DOP": {
            "code": "DOP",
            "value": 0.043735
        },
        "DOT": {
            "code": "DOT",
            "value": 0.000123
        },
        "DZD": {
            "code": "DZD",
            "value": 0.106398
        },
        "EGP": {
            "code": "EGP",
            "value": 0.023798
        },
        "ERN": {
            "code": "ERN",
            "value": 0.011676
        },
        "ETB": {
            "code": "ETB",
            "value": 0.041827
        },
        "ETH": {
            "code": "ETH",
            "value": 0
        },
        "EUR": {
            "code": "EUR",
            "value": 0.000728
        },
        "FJD": {
            "code": "FJD",
            "value": 0.001706
        },
        "FKP": {
            "code": "FKP",
            "value": 0.000647
        },
        "GBP": {
            "code": "GBP",
            "value": 0.000646
        },
        "GEL": {
            "code": "GEL",
            "value": 0.002067
        },
        "GGP": {
            "code": "GGP",
            "value": 0.000647
        },
        "GHS": {
            "code": "GHS",
            "value": 0.009632
        },
        "GIP": {
            "code": "GIP",
            "value": 0.000647
        },
        "GMD": {
            "code": "GMD",
            "value": 0.047601
        },
        "GNF": {
            "code": "GNF",
            "value": 6.70225
        },
        "GTQ": {
            "code": "GTQ",
            "value": 0.006094
        },
        "GYD": {
            "code": "GYD",
            "value": 0.164233
        },
        "HKD": {
            "code": "HKD",
            "value": 0.00611
        },
        "HNL": {
            "code": "HNL",
            "value": 0.019186
        },
        "HTG": {
            "code": "HTG",
            "value": 0.116942
        },
        "HUF": {
            "code": "HUF",
            "value": 0.276597
        },
        "IDR": {
            "code": "IDR",
            "value": 11.864333
        },
        "ILS": {
            "code": "ILS",
            "value": 0.002746
        },
        "IMP": {
            "code": "IMP",
            "value": 0.000647
        },
        "INR": {
            "code": "INR",
            "value": 0.064507
        },
        "IQD": {
            "code": "IQD",
            "value": 1.135978
        },
        "IRR": {
            "code": "IRR",
            "value": 32.888583
        },
        "ISK": {
            "code": "ISK",
            "value": 0.111985
        },
        "JEP": {
            "code": "JEP",
            "value": 0.000647
        },
        "JMD": {
            "code": "JMD",
            "value": 0.120157
        },
        "JOD": {
            "code": "JOD",
            "value": 0.000553
        },
        "JPY": {
            "code": "JPY",
            "value": 0.10407
        },
        "KES": {
            "code": "KES",
            "value": 0.097763
        },
        "KGS": {
            "code": "KGS",
            "value": 0.0677
        },
        "KHR": {
            "code": "KHR",
            "value": 3.180334
        },
        "KMF": {
            "code": "KMF",
            "value": 0.357201
        },
        "KPW": {
            "code": "KPW",
            "value": 0.70051
        },
        "KRW": {
            "code": "KRW",
            "value": 1
        },
        "KWD": {
            "code": "KWD",
            "value": 0.000238
        },
        "KYD": {
            "code": "KYD",
            "value": 0.000649
        },
        "KZT": {
            "code": "KZT",
            "value": 0.347961
        },
        "LAK": {
            "code": "LAK",
            "value": 13.112856
        },
        "LBP": {
            "code": "LBP",
            "value": 11.682782
        },
        "LKR": {
            "code": "LKR",
            "value": 0.284092
        },
        "LRD": {
            "code": "LRD",
            "value": 0.122369
        },
        "LSL": {
            "code": "LSL",
            "value": 0.013942
        },
        "LTC": {
            "code": "LTC",
            "value": 8.0e-6
        },
        "LTL": {
            "code": "LTL",
            "value": 0.002298
        },
        "LVL": {
            "code": "LVL",
            "value": 0.000471
        },
        "LYD": {
            "code": "LYD",
            "value": 0.00373
        },
        "MAD": {
            "code": "MAD",
            "value": 0.008016
        },
        "MATIC": {
            "code": "MATIC",
            "value": 0.000611
        },
        "MDL": {
            "code": "MDL",
            "value": 0.014574
        },
        "MGA": {
            "code": "MGA",
            "value": 3.340641
        },
        "MKD": {
            "code": "MKD",
            "value": 0.044773
        },
        "MMK": {
            "code": "MMK",
            "value": 1.634501
        },
        "MNT": {
            "code": "MNT",
            "value": 2.741876
        },
        "MOP": {
            "code": "MOP",
            "value": 0.006292
        },
        "MRO": {
            "code": "MRO",
            "value": 0.277898
        },
        "MUR": {
            "code": "MUR",
            "value": 0.035605
        },
        "MVR": {
            "code": "MVR",
            "value": 0.011949
        },
        "MWK": {
            "code": "MWK",
            "value": 0.798893
        },
        "MXN": {
            "code": "MXN",
            "value": 0.014527
        },
        "MYR": {
            "code": "MYR",
            "value": 0.003419
        },
        "MZN": {
            "code": "MZN",
            "value": 0.049119
        },
        "NAD": {
            "code": "NAD",
            "value": 0.013942
        },
        "NGN": {
            "code": "NGN",
            "value": 0.358513
        },
        "NIO": {
            "code": "NIO",
            "value": 0.028441
        },
        "NOK": {
            "code": "NOK",
            "value": 0.007938
        },
        "NPR": {
            "code": "NPR",
            "value": 0.103111
        },
        "NZD": {
            "code": "NZD",
            "value": 0.001241
        },
        "OMR": {
            "code": "OMR",
            "value": 0.0003
        },
        "PAB": {
            "code": "PAB",
            "value": 0.000778
        },
        "PEN": {
            "code": "PEN",
            "value": 0.002993
        },
        "PGK": {
            "code": "PGK",
            "value": 0.002743
        },
        "PHP": {
            "code": "PHP",
            "value": 0.043029
        },
        "PKR": {
            "code": "PKR",
            "value": 0.20645
        },
        "PLN": {
            "code": "PLN",
            "value": 0.003466
        },
        "PYG": {
            "code": "PYG",
            "value": 5.665336
        },
        "QAR": {
            "code": "QAR",
            "value": 0.002834
        },
        "RON": {
            "code": "RON",
            "value": 0.003566
        },
        "RSD": {
            "code": "RSD",
            "value": 0.085355
        },
        "RUB": {
            "code": "RUB",
            "value": 0.057807
        },
        "RWF": {
            "code": "RWF",
            "value": 0.845186
        },
        "SAR": {
            "code": "SAR",
            "value": 0.00292
        },
        "SBD": {
            "code": "SBD",
            "value": 0.006392
        },
        "SCR": {
            "code": "SCR",
            "value": 0.010389
        },
        "SDG": {
            "code": "SDG",
            "value": 0.454602
        },
        "SEK": {
            "code": "SEK",
            "value": 0.008098
        },
        "SGD": {
            "code": "SGD",
            "value": 0.001039
        },
        "SHP": {
            "code": "SHP",
            "value": 0.000947
        },
        "SLL": {
            "code": "SLL",
            "value": 15.373958
        },
        "SOL": {
            "code": "SOL",
            "value": 3.5e-5
        },
        "SOS": {
            "code": "SOS",
            "value": 0.443315
        },
        "SRD": {
            "code": "SRD",
            "value": 0.02528
        },
        "STD": {
            "code": "STD",
            "value": 16.111862
        },
        "SVC": {
            "code": "SVC",
            "value": 0.00681
        },
        "SYP": {
            "code": "SYP",
            "value": 1.955824
        },
        "SZL": {
            "code": "SZL",
            "value": 0.013994
        },
        "THB": {
            "code": "THB",
            "value": 0.026762
        },
        "TJS": {
            "code": "TJS",
            "value": 0.008126
        },
        "TMT": {
            "code": "TMT",
            "value": 0.002724
        },
        "TND": {
            "code": "TND",
            "value": 0.00243
        },
        "TOP": {
            "code": "TOP",
            "value": 0.001815
        },
        "TRY": {
            "code": "TRY",
            "value": 0.014672
        },
        "TTD": {
            "code": "TTD",
            "value": 0.005282
        },
        "TWD": {
            "code": "TWD",
            "value": 0.023579
        },
        "TZS": {
            "code": "TZS",
            "value": 1.820522
        },
        "UAH": {
            "code": "UAH",
            "value": 0.028745
        },
        "UGX": {
            "code": "UGX",
            "value": 2.856504
        },
        "USD": {
            "code": "USD",
            "value": 0.000778
        },
        "UYU": {
            "code": "UYU",
            "value": 0.030382
        },
        "UZS": {
            "code": "UZS",
            "value": 8.848938
        },
        "VEF": {
            "code": "VEF",
            "value": 1883.620605
        },
        "VND": {
            "code": "VND",
            "value": 18.390362
        },
        "VUV": {
            "code": "VUV",
            "value": 0.090749
        },
        "WST": {
            "code": "WST",
            "value": 0.002115
        },
        "XAF": {
            "code": "XAF",
            "value": 0.476658
        },
        "XAG": {
            "code": "XAG",
            "value": 3.6e-5
        },
        "XAU": {
            "code": "XAU",
            "value": 0
        },
        "XCD": {
            "code": "XCD",
            "value": 0.002104
        },
        "XDR": {
            "code": "XDR",
            "value": 0.00058
        },
        "XOF": {
            "code": "XOF",
            "value": 0.476658
        },
        "XPF": {
            "code": "XPF",
            "value": 0.086911
        },
        "XRP": {
            "code": "XRP",
            "value": 0.001996
        },
        "YER": {
            "code": "YER",
            "value": 0.194841
        },
        "ZAR": {
            "code": "ZAR",
            "value": 0.014003
        },
        "ZMK": {
            "code": "ZMK",
            "value": 7.006775
        },
        "ZMW": {
            "code": "ZMW",
            "value": 0.015041
        },
        "ZWL": {
            "code": "ZWL",
            "value": 0.250653
        }
    }
}
```

I used the model below to decode the JSON above.

```
import Foundation

struct CurrencyAPIResponse_Latest: Codable {
    let meta: Meta
    let data: [String: Currency]
}

struct Currency: Codable {
    let code: String
    let value: Float
}

struct Meta: Codable {
    let lastUpdatedAt: Date
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lastUpdatedAt = "last_updated_at"
    }
}
```

Honestly, I'm not good at parsing JSON, so I couldn't even try to fix this error. I just can't understand why it keeps failing. Any help??

Comment: You didn't include the code where you decode but my guess is that you forgot to tell the decoder how to parse the date. You do this by setting the `dateDecodingStrategy` property on the decoder, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895216-datedecodingstrategy. It looks like that `.iso8601` should work.

Comment: Also note that you don't have to include any keys that you don't need. If you don't require that date, or you don't need the whole `meta` object, you can just leave them out of your data structure and they'll be ignored. This may be simpler than working out the right way to parse the date if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One helpful thing to do is to paste your code, along with JSON (in `"""` quotes to allow multiline pasting) into playground and run it there.

So when I do, the error I see is this:

> typeMismatch : 2 elements
>
> - .0 : Swift.Double
>   ▿ .1 : Context
>   ▿ codingPath : 2 elements
>
>   - 0 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "meta", intValue: nil)
>   - 1 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "last_updated_at", intValue: nil)
>   - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead."
>   - underlyingError : nil

which says pretty clearly where the problem is: you expect `lastUpdatedAt` to be a `Date` in

```
let lastUpdatedAt: Date
```

but it's a string:

```
"last_updated_at": "2023-02-15T12:59:59Z"
```

So you have 3 options:

**Option 1**: Set the date decoding strategy for the `JSONDecoder`. Since the format of your date is ISO8601, this will work:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
```

**Option 2**: If you cannot / don't want to change `JSONDecoder()`'s `dateDecodingStrategy`, you can make a custom conversion:

```
struct Meta: Codable {
    
    static let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    
    let lastUpdatedAt: Date?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let containter = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let dateAsString = try containter.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastUpdatedAt)
        lastUpdatedAt = Self.formatter.date(from: dateAsString)
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lastUpdatedAt = "last_updated_at"
    }
}
```

Note that parsing may fail, and for that reason I changed `lastUpdatedAt` to optional. You can change the parsing in a different way.

**Option 3**: Finally, you don't always need a conversion to happen right away. In that case you can change the model to accept a string, and convert it to date later, when you actually need a date.

```
struct Meta: Codable {
    
    let lastUpdatedAt: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lastUpdatedAt = "last_updated_at"
    }
}

// ...

extension String {
    
    static let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    
    var toISO8601Date: Date? {
        String.formatter.date(from: self)
    }
}

// Used as

let date = meta.lastUpdatedAt.toISO8601Date
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson because you already suggested strategy in the comment, I didn't include it here, since I wanted to show other options. And neat-picking on a demo solution, like you did with `using a formatter in the init is another strange solution` comment, is absolutely pointless: the point of SO is to show people the way, not to deliver them a code they can use without thinking. Besides, if it bugs you that much, you could edit it.

Comment: Knowledge is power. Someday OP is going to need to parse something in a way that requires more than setting `dateDecodingStrategy` to a predefined value.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example you could use.

```
// MARK: - APIResponse
struct APIResponse: Codable {
    let meta: Meta
    let data: [String:Currency]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case meta = "meta"
        case data = "data"
    }
    
    // Initializers
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
    }
    init(string: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = string.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }
    
}

// MARK: - Currency
struct Currency: Codable {
    let code: String
    let value: Float

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "code"
        case value = "value"
    }
}

// MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Codable {
    let lastUpdatedAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lastUpdatedAt = "last_updated_at"
    }
}
```

To decode the string or data:

*Of course you have to replace `jsonString` or `jsonData`. Either with a **JSON string**, or with the **JSON data** from the server. :-)*

```
do {
    // String Example:
    let apiResponse = try APIResponse(string: jsonString)
    
    // From Data Example:
    let apiResponse = try APIResponse(data: jsonData)
    
    // print(apiResponse.meta.lastUpdatedAt)   // "2023-02-15T12:59:59"
    // print(apiResponse.data.count)           // "176"
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```